# Changing the value in a file dynamically from python

Tags: python

I have a php file. And in the php file, I have such a statement:

```
"$limit_value = ..."
```

I want to change this limit value dynamically by using python. It means, there is no any default limit value. It is going to change whenever I run the python statement. And the .php file will be modified.

For instance,

```
"$limit_value = 5"
"$limit_value = 500"
"$limit_value = 34"
...
```

I have found similar solutions on stackoverflow, but none of them references to the exact issue of mine.

Could you give me a simple example to solve my issue?

Thanks

Comment: what di you mean "dynamically"?

Comment: Yes, but haven't said what you mean saying "dynamically".

Comment: Okay, I'm editing again.

Comment: Do you want to modify the php file to replace '...' with a specific value?

Comment: Can you please describe why do you need this? Looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) for me.

Comment: You can probably make use of [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

Comment: This php fetches a data from somewhere. One of the needed values for fetching is this limit_value which changing dynamically in python.

Comment: Use a command line argument to PHP (if its a shell script), or a querystring argument (if PHP is a web application) and then call it with the appropriate value from Python.

Comment: No, thank you Burhan. I'm sure %(100x100) I need to modify php by using python. I have thought about this, and I decided that this is the best way I can do. It is not impossible, right?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Who calls the Python script? Where is the new limit value coming from? I find it hard to believe that this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `index.php` and it looks something like this:

```
<?php
    $limit_value = 0;
    echo $limit_value;
?>
```

You could in python do:

```
import re
rep = re.compile('\$limit_value =.*;')

with open('/path/to/file/index.php', 'r+') as php:
    data = rep.sub('$limit_value = 5;', php.read())
    php.seek(0) # Places the text "Input" in the file at the beginning of the file
    php.write(data)
    php.truncate() # This will cause all trailing data to be flushed.
                            # reason for doing this is because your default value of `$limit_value` might
                            # make your total content written back to the file shorter of that was writter before.
                            # there for there might be trailing data we need to truncate away.
```

This will create a regexp object that will find anything named `$limit_value =<anything>;` and replace it with `$limit_value = 5;` assuming 5 is the default value you want to use.

**Verified**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNTkV.png

Comment: Sorry Torxed, it worked at first, but I don't know why it doesn't change again :)

Comment: @yusuf Ah my bad. I forgot to add the trailing `;` - if you look carefully at my output hehe. I'll correct that.

Comment: No, @Torxed, I have already fixed that. The thing is, limit value has changed the first time, but it didn't change again :)

Comment: What do you mean by, "again"? Do you want it to automatically update with say `*2` or? Because this is a **static** change to `5` to show you how you can update the content. I have no idea what sort of formula or baseline you use to get the value you desire. Simply modify the `=5` to fit your needs?

Comment: for instance, the limit value was 12 at the first time. Then it has changed as 3. It was fine. Now I wanted to change it again. But limit value doesn't change again. It is still 3.

Comment: string = '$limit_value = ' + str(len(nameListing)) + ';' data = rep.sub(string, php.read())

Comment: Are you sure `nameListing` is of a different length? Can you print it out to the console to verify?

Comment: Yes, unfotunately I'm sure @Torxed.

Comment: Works perfectly well here. http://i.imgur.com/q58kxmz.png

Could you create a https://gist.github.com/ and perhaps show us all of your code?

Comment: now it worked. I have changed re.compile('\$limit_value =.*;') with re.compile('\$limit_value =.*').

Comment: Then you didn't fix `re.sub(...)` to contain `;`. Your change is dangerous since it can match other things after `$limit_value =`, especially if you have one-liners in your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want:

```
~/Desktop> cat a.php
<?php
// foo
$limit_value = 5317
// bar
?>
~/Desktop> cat a.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import re
import sys
import random

phpfile = sys.argv[1]
tmpf = "." + phpfile + ".edit"
r = "$limit_value = %d\n" % random.randint(1, 10000)
with open(phpfile) as f:
    with open(tmpf, 'w') as g:
        for line in f:
            g.write(re.sub(r'^\$limit_value\s*=\s*[0-9]*\s*$', r, line))
os.unlink(phpfile)
os.rename(tmpf, phpfile)
~/Desktop> python a.py a.php
~/Desktop> cat a.php
<?php
// foo
$limit_value = 360
// bar
?>
```

It creates a copy of the file with the modified contents, and renames it over the initial file (on Windows, you have to delete the destination file first, on Linux it could be atomic).

That said, the comments on your question are right. There might be better ways, e.g. your PHP script could receive that limit differently, whether configuration files, environment, query arguments etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os, sys
text = "$limit_value = "
new_limit_value = sys.argv[1]
new=open("new.php",'w')
with open('myphp.php', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if text in line:
            line = line.strip()
            line = text+str(new_limit_value)+'\n'
        new.write(line)
new.close()
os.rename('myphp.php', 'myphp.php.old')
os.rename('new.php', 'myphp.php')
```

call with `python mypython.py 42`
changes the `$limit_value =` line to `$limit_value = 42`
Alter to use sys.argv[1] to be php filename and sys.argv[2] to be the limit value, if the php filename is variable as well as the limit value